# Why isn't the random number sequence the same?

Tags: vb.net, random

I wrote this code below, expecting it to return the same thing each time I ran it, and it did not. May someone explain to me why A specifically seeded Random Number Generator would generate a different number each time I run it, because i wrote the same program as a command line application and it worked just fine.

Here is my VB.NET code (broken code):

```
'Bunch of WinForms Code
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
   Randomize(3)
   MsgBox(Rnd.ToString)
End Sub
```

Here is my working VB.NET Command Line Application:

```
Imports System.Console
Public Module rnum
    Sub Main()
        Randomize(3)
        WriteLine(Rnd.ToString) 'Returns 0.1387751
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt(v=vs.90).aspx): `To repeat sequences of random numbers, call Rnd with a negative argument immediately before using Randomize with a numeric argument. Using Randomize with the same value for Number does not repeat the previous sequence.`

Comment: Then why did it work in the command line application?

Comment: @Plutonix that still doesn't answer my question of why it works in the command line app

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `Rnd` as opposed to the `Random` class? As I recall 'Rnd' is for VB6, and `Random` is what you are supposed to use for VB.NET.

Comment: because I want a number between 0 and 1, and `Random` doesn't do that, as far as im aware

Comment: @NathanC -- That's not relevant.  The question stands as is.  And it's a damn good question, actually.  I'm scratching my head and pouring through the decompiled code.

Comment: @NullSpark the Random class has a NextDouble function that you can call to give you a number in the range of [0, 1)

Comment: As rightly pointed out, I have deleted my answer since it did not address the `Rnd` function. However, as noted [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET/Visual_Basic_6_to_.NET_Function_Equivalents) the `Rnd` and `Randomize` calls are deprecetaed in VB.NET. If you are creating a random number generator from scratch, it is recommended that you use `Random`.

Comment: @NathanC it is not deprecated.  If it was it would be so noted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt(v=vs.90).aspx) and it is not. `Randomize` and `Rnd`  for better or worse, are part of the VB language.

Comment: `I want a number between 0 and 1, and Random doesn't do that,` sure it does: `RNG.NextDouble()`

Comment: @Plutonix I said, "As far as I'm aware" And I will admit that I am still a Comp Sci student and not a professional with a lot of experience under my belt (also, someone else already said that)

Comment: @Plutonix it may not be officially deprecated, but it is certainly unofficially deprecated. Most sources mention that `Random` should be used instead like [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=ijM7PDa36KIC&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=vb6+to+vb.net+randomize+conversion&source=bl&ots=tdl8Px-5u_&sig=WzDZZn_5vAGEQfLGsIh8oyS5SpI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq4bvmwL3KAhUGgj4KHedmBU0Q6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=vb6%20to%20vb.net%20randomize%20conversion&f=false). So it is deprecated in the sense that it is still usable, but is not the recommended approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if you put the console code into a loop? I'm betting you would receive the same sequence of numbers. The console is running 1 time and producing the first result whereas if you click the button multiple times, you're in essence looping through the randomize results.

When I do this, 4 times I receive the same 4 numbers when I click the button 4 times.

```
Sub Main()
    For x As Integer = 0 To 3
        Randomize(3)
        Console.WriteLine(Rnd.ToString) 'Returns 0.1387751
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

produces:
0.1387751
0.05591547
0.8356526
0.2308619

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Randomize(3)
    MsgBox(Rnd.ToString)
End Sub
```

produces
0.1387751 on 1st click
0.05591547 on 2nd click
0.8356526 on 3rd click
0.2308619 on 4th click

Comment: @NullSpark -- This is the right answer.  It's because the console application exits.  If you click the picture box once and close the form app (thus mimicking what the console app is actually doing), you'll see the same results with the same number over and over again.  I can't believe I didn't see it before!

Comment: @roryap It didnt do that for me though. That is what had me so confused

Comment: You mean if you run your form, click your picture box, close the form (i.e. exit the application entirely), run the form again, click the picture box, and so on, you don't get the same number over and over again -- the number that you get with the console app?

Comment: @roryap Nope. I got a completely different sequence with each run of the application. (How that works I have no idea)

Comment: Did you try to call Rnd with a negative number before calling Randomize?

Comment: Strange.  I wasn't getting that.  What version of .net, visual studio, OS?

Comment: @roryap Visual Studio 2015, Windows 8.1 Pro, Which ever comes with VS.NET 2015

Comment: I wish I could try the negative number idea, but i still dont have acess to my PC right now (im on chromebook)